# Winforms - UI tools

Tags: winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Form Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100301/windows-form-developer-tools)

Is there anything similar to the browser's developer tools in Winforms?
I want to be able to check while debugging which control is where i'm pointing..

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for, but with Spy++ you can get controls info and messages

Comment: I want to be able to take my mouse pointer, point on any area of my form window, and to know which control resides there.

Comment: You want to know full name of .net class, which represents control? Or just to get control name?

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

- [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460725.aspx) - a tool shipped with Visual Studio, which allows to view properties of selected windows, threads, processes, or messages.
- [Hawkeye](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/) - a tool that allows you to view, edit, analyze and invoke (almost) any object from a .Net application.